# In a for/while loop, after a conditional is met, does it read any following ones?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Hi guys so I have got this very basic question that is very dumb but I'm not very certain of. Let's imagine I had the following code:

```
for num in range(1, 11):
    if type(num) == int:
        print(num)
    elif type(num) != str:
        print("hej")
    print("after")
    print("lol")
```

I am aware of the output being `1\n"after"\n"lol"` and so on, but is that because after a condition is met the other ones are skipped, in other words after on of the conditions is met it skips anything that has the syntax of `if/elif/else x ==/!=/>/< (etc) y:` and the contents inside of it?

Comment: Are you essentially asking why `"hej"` isn't printed? The `elif` condition isn't checked if a condition before it was already true.

Comment: This isn't a symptom of a loop, it's how conditionals work. The program will stop reading conditions after the first one is met (for a single `if/elif/.../else` block) and won't execute the code contained in those other branches

Comment: if the `if` condition evaluates to  `True`, then the `elif` expression is not even evaluated so  the code it controls will never be executed.

Answer (score 1):

In an if/elif/else chain, once a condition is satisfied, the other blocks are skipped completely. This is one of the main reasons to use if/elif/else chains.

For example, say you wanted to get the first element in a list, but sometimes the list is actually `None`. Simply doing:

```
print(my_list[0])
```

would sometimes result in an error, since `None` is not subscriptable. Instead, you can use an if/elif/else chain:

```
if not isinstance(my_list, list):
    print("that's not a list!")
elif len(my_list) == 0:
    print("that list is too short!")
else:
    print(my_list[0])
```

By using an if/elif/else chain, we can avoid the errors that would be raised by trying to access index 0 of either a None object or an empty list.